# Stream stream = WriteableBitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream() missing

Tags: c#, windows-8, buffer, extension-methods

I'm writing windows store app (8.1) and I have sample (probably for win 8.0):

```
private WriteableBitmap WriteableBitmap;
…
WriteableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(500,500);
…
using (Stream stream = WriteableBitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
{
    …
}
```

So I have created new win 8.1 project and trying to do it same way, but when I get to:

```
using (Stream stream = WriteableBitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
```

My project dont recognize `*.AsStream()` method, can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Are you missing a reference?

Comment: The extension method lives in the `System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime` assembly so you will need a reference to it and also put in a using  `System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime` for the namespace.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
```