# 'using' Statement being ignored

Tags: c#, bitmap, reference, include

With the function below, I'm running into problems trying to access the WriteableBitmap.PixelBuffer property. The message I am getting is:

```
'WriteableBitmap' does not contain a definition for 'PixelBuffer' and no extension method 'PixelBuffer' accepting a first argument of type 'WriteableBitmap' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I have read other places that I need to include

```
 using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
```

But when I use this include, nothing changes in my code. Looking through the references of my solution, I don't see anything like System.Runtime.InteropServices. Im frustrated as this seems to be the solution to other people trying to access the PixelBuffer of a WriteableBitmap.

```
private WriteableBitmap ChangeBrightness(WriteableBitmap source, byte change_value)
    {
        WriteableBitmap dest = new WriteableBitmap(source);

        byte[] color = new byte[4];

        using (Stream s = source.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
        {
            using (Stream d = dest.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
            {
                // read the pixel color
                while (s.Read(color, 0, 4) > 0)
                {
                    // color[0] = b
                    // color[1] = g 
                    // color[2] = r
                    // color[3] = a

                    // do the adding algo per byte (skip the alpha)
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                    {
                        if ((int)color[i] + change_value > 255) color[i] = 255; else color[i] = (byte)(color[i] + change_value);
                    }

                    // write the new pixel color
                    d.Write(color, 0, 4);
                }
            }
        }

        // return the new bitmap
        return dest;
    }
```

Comment: What part of your code isn't working?  `WriteableBitmap` isn't recognized or what?

Comment: `PixelBuffer` seems to be a member of [`Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.writeablebitmap#Windows_UI_Xaml_Media_Imaging_WriteableBitmap_PixelBuffer), have you used the wrong one?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20478467/stream-stream-writeablebitmap-pixelbuffer-asstream-missing this seems relevant, in particular the comment on the question about the assembly/namespace

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are referencing the assembly that package belongs to:

`System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime` assembly

Comment: I could not find that assembly when I went to add a reference. I ended up solving my problem another way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up going about solving my original problem via other means. To adjust the brightness of my image, I ended up using this functions instead:

```
    public ImageSource AdjustBrightness(BitmapImage Image, int Value, int mod)
    {
        Bitmap TempBitmap = BitmapImage2Bitmap(Image);

        Bitmap NewBitmap = new Bitmap(TempBitmap.Width, TempBitmap.Height);

        Graphics NewGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(NewBitmap);

        float FinalValue = (float)Value / 255.0f;

        float[][] FloatColorMatrix ={

                 new float[] {1, 0, 0, 0, 0},

                 new float[] {0, 1, 0, 0, 0},

                 new float[] {0, 0, 1, 0, 0},

                 new float[] {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},

                 new float[] {mod * FinalValue, mod * FinalValue, mod * FinalValue, 1, 1}
             };

        ColorMatrix NewColorMatrix = new ColorMatrix(FloatColorMatrix);

        ImageAttributes Attributes = new ImageAttributes();

        Attributes.SetColorMatrix(NewColorMatrix);

        NewGraphics.DrawImage(TempBitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, TempBitmap.Width, TempBitmap.Height), 0, 0, TempBitmap.Width, TempBitmap.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, Attributes);

        Attributes.Dispose();

        NewGraphics.Dispose();

        return Bitmap2BitmapImage(NewBitmap);
    }
```